# How to avoid cropped data labels in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a bar chart where the data labels will be generated by a formatter function. Unfortunately some of the labels run to long and will be cropped by the chart container. Is there any way to adjust the chart so the labels will fit into the chart.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it by adding a padding to the right side of the chart options:

```
{
  chart: {
    marginRight: 100
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'some title'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Btw, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/FpKjQ/18/ Already fixed by crop option so dataLabels won't be cut off.

Comment: Is this your own fix, or some official one? It works nicely, but I need to use the official update of highcharts for my customer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use crop parameter http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.crop

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to add a margin. Use 'marginRight: *some number*' in the chart options

Broken Example -> 
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kZMYd/5/ (june is cut off)

```
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'bar',
},
```

Fixed Example ->
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kZMYd/6/

```
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'bar',
    marginRight: 40
},
```

Set crop to false, setting it to true will end up removing the data label